# Schema Aware XSL 2.0: How to distinguish between values from source XML and schema during transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, schema, xslt-2.0, default-value

I'm using a schema-aware transformation with XSLT 2.0.  I have a source XML document, and here's an example node from it:

```
<ns:IssueNumber>
    <ns:Value>7232</ns:Value>
</ns:IssueNumber>
```

Here's the schema that defines that node:

```
<xs:element name="IssueNumber">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="ns:Value"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional" fixed="$issueNum"/>
        <xs:attribute name="nickname" type="xs:string" use="optional" default="Issue Number"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I use the identity transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The transformer (XMLSpy 2013) always fills in the default values for all of those attributes.

```
<ns:IssueNumber nickname="Issue Number" name="$issueNum">
    <ns:Value>7232</ns:Value>
</ns:IssueNumber>
```

I would like to be able to set different output behaviors for these attributes, however, based on whether they were set in the original XML input (rather than supplied by the schema's type definition).  I'd also like to be able to compare these attributes' values to their defaults.

My fundamental question is this: is there an **xsl:test** expression for distinguishing whether the value of an attribute or element was set by the input or by the schema?

I'd like to do something along the following lines and make it **generic across all attributes**.  It doesn't do me much good if the solution is specific to the schema I've described.

```
// Algorithm
// (I know this is clearly not similar to XSL syntax.)
//
For each attribute A in (Set of all attributes)
{
    if (A.value was set by Schema)
    {
        doBehaviorX();
    }
    else if (A.value == A.DefaultSchemaValue)
    {
        doBehaviorY();
    }
    else
    {
        doDefaultBehavior();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, this isn't possible. There's nothing in the XDM data model that distinguishes attributes resulting from expansion of XSD-defined defaults.

Comment: Well, darn.  Doesn't break things for me, but it would have been nice to have.  Where could I put in a request to have the XDM data model amended for this purpose in a future release?

Comment: The W3C specs all have a status section explaining how to submit feedback. At present the 3.1 specs are nearing completion which means that getting new features in is unlikely, and there are no immediate plans for the version after that. Even with the new feature in the specs, there's no guarantee that any particular vendor will upgrade their products on any particuular timescale.

Comment: I have implemented the feature as an extension function saxon:is-defaulted() for Saxon 9.7. Thanks for the suggestion.